# How I can highlight some words of a tab's content using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some image with a url. When the image is clicked, the corresponding tab is opened. I would like that in the tab some words are highlighted . Is it possible? How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: If you mean the browser tab, I don't think you can do this, maybe as a browser plugin.

Comment: *Is it possible?* Yes (if the site is not an external site you don't have control over)

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question and possibly give an example of what you want in a fiddler

Comment: always want the same word/list of words to be highlighted (or) is the list of words dynamic? if static list, just put the words within span and style with background color.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap those words in `<span>...</span>` and add some classes to thoose spans.

Comment: That is only going to work if it is the same domain / the OPs own page / website.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to highlight the div included word("John") ;

```
$( "div:contains('John')" ).css('background-color', 'red');
```

[jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

If you need to highlight word only

```
var html = $('div').html();
$('div').html(html.replace(/John/gi, '<strong>$&</strong>'));
```

I found this [plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/fw6Pk/) develop by someone and you can use same thing for your task

Comment: I think this would highlight the entire `div` and not just the word.

Comment: I made some changes in the answer